# How to create wall post in jsp using servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I want to create wall post in jsp using servlet. How to attach sender and date information on post? I use MVC architecture with servlets and jsp.

Model Class:

```
public class Comments {

    int comment_id;
    String comment;

    public Comments(){

    }

    public Comments(int comment_id,String comment){

        this.comment_id = comment_id;
        this.comment  =  comment;

    }
    ...Generated getters and setters methods
```

Servlet Class:

```
@WebServlet("/comment")
public class CommentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String comment = request.getParameter("comment");
        int case = new CommentDao().addComment(comment);
        response.sendRedirect("comment.jsp");

    }
}
```

Dao Class:

```
public class CommentDao {

public int addComment(String comment){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", "root", "***");

            String query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES (?)";

            PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            psmt.setString(1, comment);
            return psmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public List<Comments> getList() {
        List<Comments> r = new ArrayList<Comments>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:/db", "root", "***");
            String query = "Select * from comments";
            PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Comments com =  new Comments(rs.getInt("comment_id"), rs.getString("comment"));
                r.add(com);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

comment.jsp:

```
 <h2>Comment</h2>
      <div id="respond">
        <form action="comment" method="post" name="form">
          <p>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10"></textarea>
            <label for="comment" style="display:none;"><small>Comment (required)</small></label>

             <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Share" />
          </p>

        <h1>Comment List</h1>
        <c:forEach items="${commnet}" var="c">

            <div align="center">
                <textarea readonly name="comment">${c.comment}</textarea>
            </div>  

        </c:forEach>
       </form>
     </div>
```

When I shared wall post , display this post in same jsp page. But I cannot attach sender and date information.How to do this?

Comment: Where are you expecting to get sender and date from?

Comment: I sharing post on user profile wall and after I want to display this post with sender and date. I want to create facebook style wall post.

Comment: In you Comments class, you should have attributes that retain sender and date data. Perhaps, your first focus should be on the data model of a wall posing, then create objects that can used to persist and retain data that you need.